# ¿Como crear interfaces gráficos en Java?

Tags: java

¿Cómo podría hacer una interfaz gráfica en Java?

Estoy tratando de hacer un programa al estilo "trivago" pero no entiendo muy bien esto de las interfaces gráficas (Por ello recurro a que me puedan ayudar)

Quisiera que el programa al abrir generase un recuadro que estuviese ahí con toda la información del programa y demás (Lo típico) pero no sé hacerlo (Y no me gusta usar JOptionPane)

Comment: Los marcos de trabajo para java mas importantes son Swing y java fx. Swing es muy fácil de aprender.

Comment: Ya que no entiendes bien puedes utilizar NetBeans el cuál cuenta con una paleta de componentes de la librería **swing** los cuáles sólo 'arrastras' y 'sueltas' donde los quieras colocar

Comment: Pregunta basada en opiniones...

Comment: Bueno, tienes varias opciones para generar interfaces gráficas con Java. Primero diferencia si quieres una aplicación web o una aplicación de escritorio. Si hablamos de escritorio el que más completo es, por experiencia personal, es la api Swing. Y mejor aún, usando un IDE como Eclipse, te da la posibildiad de incluir el Swing Designer, que te ayudará muchísimo a la hora de organizar tus objetos Swing. Suerte!

Answer (score 1):

Si quieres desarrollar una aplicación de escritorio, necesitas usar: *Java Swing*, *JavaFx*, *AjaxSwing*.

Si quieres un sitio web con *Java* necesitas usar diferentes tecnologías:

**Para el lado de Back-end**

Deberías empezar por *Java Enterprise Edition* (*JEE*), la cual te permitirá crear aplicaciones web. Adicionalmente, es muy común el uso de frameworks para agilizar el desarrollo. Ejemplos: *Spring* (*MVC*, *Boot*, *Security*), *Struts*.

También, necesitarás una base de datos. Ejemplos: *MySQL*, *SQL Server*, *Oracle*.

**Para el lado de Front-end**

Tienes muchas alternativas, entre las más populares, tienes *Angular*, *React*, *jQuery*. Esto, por lo general, va acompañado de la maquetación donde puedes usar *Bootstrap*.

Todo eso va alojado en un servidor de aplicaciones, como pueden ser *JBoss* o *Tomcat*.